# Crossfade between TWO audio files - Swift

Tags: swift

I’ve been looking for a solution for this for the past week and still haven’t found it.

My goal is to crossfade between two audio files that are each loaded into a collection view using DidSelectItem. The problem is getting one to stop and the other one to play seamlessly without clicks or pops.

Things I’ve tried:

1. Github [cephalopod](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cephalopod) library
2. Multiple AVAudioPlayers

If anyone can point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Comment: As a suggestion, you might want post the code that's causing a problem. Also, it's always a good idea to post a link to the library you're asking about.

Comment: why would you think that you'd need an external library for that? what was the issue you have faced in case of `AVAudioPlayer`?

Comment: Let me paste my code cause I have tried it with the built in library but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutableaudiomixinputparameters). Specifically [setVolumeRamp(fromStartVolume: toEndVolume: timeRange: CMTimeRange)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmutableaudiomixinputparameters/1386056-setvolumeramp).

You can fade one track's volume down while you fade the other track's up, and that will result in a "seamless" transition between the two.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but for some reason the audio still clicks. I’ll show you what I have I’m typing from my phone right now.

Answer (score 0):

The clicking or popping I've found can also happen when you're using a compressed audio format like this post explains.. https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/avaudioplayer-avoiding-glitches-when-playing-looped-sounds.640862/

> The reason for this is in the way compressed audio is stored compared
> to uncompressed audio. Lets say, for example, you have an uncompressed
> sound file which is 23600 samples long and you save the file as a .CAF
> file which is compressed using AAC which, for simplicity, is
> compressed at a ratio of 4:1. Ignoring the file header and (again) for
> the sake of simplicity, the data in the file is stored in blocks of
> 1024 samples. 23600 samples compressed @ 4:1 equals 5900 samples, so
> you might expect your file would look like this;
>
> block 0 : 1024 samples block 1 : 1024 samples block 2 : 1024 samples
> block 3 : 1024 samples block 4 : 1024 samples block 5 : 780 samples
>
> As you can see though, because the actual length of the sound file is
> not an exact multiple of 1024 samples, the last block only contains
> 780 samples. Because variable block lengths are not allowed (not in
> any compressed format I know but I could be wrong - it's certainly
> true of MP3/AAC) the encoder has to deal with that last block by
> padding out the end with silence. Therefore in the actual AAC file
> you'll have;
>
> block 0 : 1024 samples block 1 : 1024 samples block 2 : 1024 samples
> block 3 : 1024 samples block 4 : 1024 samples block 5 : 780 samples +
> 244 samples of silence/0
>
> This is fine for non looping sounds but the problem is obvious if you
> attempt to play this expecting a seamless loop. Your sound file should
> loop at the 5900th sample but because this would be in the middle of a
> block of 1024 samples, looping doesn't actually occur until 244
> samples later, hence you get a small pause or glitch at the loop
> point.

Switching from .mp3 to .wav solved the clicking and popping I was getting between clips.